# tikz circle picture - stamping out a shape inside of it?

Tags: tikz-pgf

i just drew some kind of circle. It looks like this:

[image]

Now I stuck with the arc part. It consists of two filldraws. One with lighter gray and the other one inside the first with `color=white`.

Is there a way to cut out the white arc part from the gray one? I want to see the two circle peaks through the white arc.

Here is the code example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{circlet/.pic = {%
 \filldraw[color=gray] (0,-0.1) arc (-90:90:0.1) -| ++ (-2,0) -- ++ (-2,-0.05) -- ++ (-0.5,-0.05) -- ++ (0.5,-0.05)-- ++ (2,-0.05) -- cycle;
 \begin{scope}[rotate=-20,transform shape]
   \filldraw[color=gray] (0,-0.1) arc (-90:90:0.1) -| ++ (-2,0) -- ++ (-2,-0.05) -- ++ (-0.5,-0.05) -- ++ (0.5,-0.05)-- ++ (2,-0.05) -- cycle;
 \end{scope}

 \filldraw[color=gray!70] (-2,0) arc (180:110:2) arc (110:-70:0.2) arc (110:180:1.6) arc (0:-180:0.2);
 \filldraw[color=white] (-1.9,0) arc (180:110:1.9) arc (110:-70:0.1) arc (110:180:1.7) arc (0:-180:0.1);

}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay] 
\path [transform shape](5,0) pic{circlet};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: "Is there a way to cut out the white arc part from the gray one?" Why you draw it in the first place?

Comment: You can use `even odd rule` to cut things out, though not filling it is surely easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather then two `filldraw` commands you can just use one `draw` command and control the thickness  with `line width`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{circlet/.pic = {%
 \filldraw[color=gray] (0,-0.1) arc (-90:90:0.1) -| ++ (-2,0) -- ++ (-2,-0.05) -- ++ (-0.5,-0.05) -- ++ (0.5,-0.05)-- ++ (2,-0.05) -- cycle;
 \begin{scope}[rotate=-20,transform shape]
   \filldraw[color=gray] (0,-0.1) arc (-90:90:0.1) -| ++ (-2,0) -- ++ (-2,-0.05) -- ++ (-0.5,-0.05) -- ++ (0.5,-0.05)-- ++ (2,-0.05) -- cycle;
 \end{scope}

\draw[color=gray!70,line width=4pt] (-2,0) arc (180:110:2) arc (110:-70:0.2) arc (110:180:1.6) arc (0:-180:0.2); 
}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay] 
\path [transform shape](5,0) pic{circlet};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]